# Select a file with changing filename by pattern

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, path, filepath

In the directory from where the python file is executed there is a DATA folder. In the data folder there is 1 file who's filename is constantly changing but by a pattern, and there are other files in the directory named something else. There is only 1 file changing like this so selecting the wrong file by this pattern is not possible, but I wonder how to select this file every time knowing that it's filename will change by this pattern.

For instance I want the full path of the filename in the PATH variable as a string.

And the filename could be File1.dat, File2.dat, File3.dat...

So the "File" and ".dat" segments will stay static but inbetween there is an integer variable that changes.

How do I put the filename of any File(n).dat file into the PATH variable?

I would like a 1 liner pythonic answer to select any such a file.

Answer (score 0):

Just glob it and take the first element.

```
glob.glob('somedirectory/*')[0]
```

Comment: I am not sure that he said there is only one file, but that there is only one file whose name follows the pattern.

Comment: So then make the glob as specific as it needs to be.

Comment: There are other files in the directory, but just 1 matching the pattern file(n).dat, I thought it's obvious, I will edit the op.